# Ruby on Rails on Windows: gem install fails, no output at all

Tags: windows, ruby, rubygems

I installed ruby through the windows installer yesterday.
All seemed fine.

Today, I went installing the `rmagick` win32 gem like so:

```
c:\ruby187\bin\gem install rmagick-2.7.1-x86-mswin32.gem
```

in the directory with the gem.

That also seemed to work fine, got the familiar

```
1 gem installed
Installing ...[all the ri and other docs].
```

But after that, I am tried:

```
c:\ruby187\bin\gem install --version '= 2.3.5' rails
```

it just returned immediately with no output. Probably doing nothing.

```
c:\ruby187\bin\gem list --local
```

the same, no output, but returns to the cmd line (no hang).

```
c:\ruby187\bin\gem install rails
c:\ruby187\bin\gem install --debug rails
c:\ruby187\bin\gem install --debug --version '= 2.3.5' rails
```

does exactly the same.
Any idea what's wrong?
I am a RoR newbie, although I already have some experience with it on linux -
but not on Windows.

Can anybody help? Really appreciated, started to get concerned now...

Comment: Please provide the exact output of gem installation. Also, Ruby should be in your path, not been called in the way you're doing.

Comment: Thanks Luis for coming back. I believe we were very unlucky with the configuration. I had to setup RoR via MS Live meeting on a client in Mexico (...). I believe, at some point, that the Live Meeting client was sending weird key strokes: while I was able to toggle my local CAPS lock, it did not have any effect on the text. I rebooted, when my boss told be we were losing time (this work was outside contract) and told be to stop it. I believe this problem was related to that LM session only, but can't check now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've already had problems for installing *rails* on windows using the command *gem install*. The solution was executing the file *cmd.exe* like Administrator. This file is encountered in path *C:\windows\system32* on Windows XP. Try do it.